# Let $x_n\to 1^{-}$ as $n\to\infty.$ Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_n\to 1^{-}$ as $n\to\infty.$

Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)^n$ always convergent or when it is convergent?

Comment: It's unknown. If $x_n=1-O(1/n^2)$ the limit is $1$. If $x_n=1-1/\sqrt{n}$ it is $0$.  If $x_n=1-1/n$ it is $e^{-1}$. It can be any value between $0$ and $1$. You can easily alternate these sequences to get examples that do not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ the limit is $1$.

If $x_n=1-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ it is $0$.

If $x_n=1-\frac{c}{n}$ it is $e^{-c}$.

Thus the limit can be any value between $0$ and $1$.

You can mix and match sequences to get examples that converge to no value. For example:

$$x_n=\begin{cases}1-\frac{1}{n^2}&n\text{ even}\\
1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$